# Installing RVM with a specific bash command format using `-s`

Tags: linux, bash, rvm

I'm trying to install RVM via bash.
According to the [installation guide on rvm.io](https://rvm.io/rvm/install), the command to do that is:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles
```

I'm, however, compelled to download the script and then run it separately. So, my bash command would attempt to execute the downloaded file (let's call it `rvm-installer`).

How can I execute `rvm-installer` using the format below:

```
/bin/bash -c './rvm-installer 2>&1'
```

Obviously, the above command is incorrect. I'm thinking it should look more like this:

```
/bin/bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles './rvm-installer 2>&1'
```

I know the above command sets my positional parameters in the correct order because of this:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
stable
--auto-dotfiles
./rvm-installer 2>&1
```

and this:

```
$ echo "$SHLVL"
2
```

But I'm confident that `rvm-installer` is not running because I replaced its contents with the following, to test but once the command above is run, I see no output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gimme a syntax error
echo "$1"
echo "Foo bar"
exit 1
```

How can I run `rvm-installer` using `-s` within the bash command format I need to use? Is there a way around using `-s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-s` is a bash argument not an `rvm-installer` argument.

The other arguments are the `rvm-installer` arguments.

So just pass those to `rvm-installer` yourself.

```
./rvm-installer stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Using the, entirely pointless, explicit call to `bash` that would look like this

```
/bin/bash -c './rvm-installer stable --auto-dotfiles 2>&1'
```

though that could just as meaningfully be this as well

```
/bin/bash rvm-installer stable --auto-dotfiles 2>&1
```

Comment: I am compelled to use the bash format mentioned above. So, it would be `/bin/bash -c './rvm-installer stable --auto-dotfiles  2>&1'`. If you can edit your answer to include this, I'll happily mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Why are you compelled to use that entirely pointless extra shell wrapping? It doesn't do anything useful for you or do anything safer or anything.

Comment: It's impossible to explain in a post but that's what I have to use as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: You said you needed to download the script and run it. That's reasonable. Requiring that exact format isn't reasonable but *shrug*.

Comment: It's not possible to explain my reasons over a single post. This is to do with a CLI framework and I have to stick to the convention unless I'm willing to hack the core which is not possible at this moment. Thanks for your answer, though.